# Make a view just like netflix app home page in android

Tags: android

I want to make a view just like netflix app home page in android and I am new in android.

How should I go about creating a such display on Android?

[image]

Comment: I would recommend that you explain **specifically** what areas concern you.

Comment: i want to make the whole home page of this app the whole area with drawer.

Comment: @AsadButt We aren't going to just throw code at you. You've got to show us what you've got so far and explain what specifically you're having problems with. The vagueness of your request suggests that you haven't even started.

Comment: @BooleanCheese i need some guide line to do this if have any please suggest as i told u i am new to android so i don't specifically know how i ll be done.

Comment: @AsadButt maybe this will help: https://guides.codepath.com/android/implementing-a-horizontal-listview-guide

Comment: @BooleanCheese appretiated (Y) thanks, but can i add a horizontal listView inside a custom cell of list ? if ur getting what i am trying to say.

Comment: @AsadButt yes, you just place the horizontal list view inside of your other views. This is extremely basic, and tells me that you should first try your hand at some beginners tutorials before actually trying to make something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RecyclerView with Horizontal orientation.

for that Use this code,

```
    recyclerviewObject.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(your activity context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

and for Data create model and assign it by Calling netflix api.

```
     AdaptorObject = new Adaptor(Activity, getData());
     recyclerviewObject.setAdapter(AdaptorObject);
```

then pass the Data to the RecyclerAdaptor.

use getData() method to get the required data from Netflix